# How many fields required for Lightning Message Channel?

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

How many fields do we need to create in Message Channel in LWC to pass data to other LWC_component and can we pass array using using Lightning Message Service?

Comment: ,consider accepting this as the answer if this helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find below sample LMS xml file with minimum fields :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningMessageChannel xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <description>Winter 20 - LMS Demo.</description>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <lightningMessageFields>
        <description>Dual list box</description>
        <fieldName>selectedValues</fieldName>
    </lightningMessageFields>
    <masterLabel>LMS_Demo</masterLabel>
</LightningMessageChannel>
```

Coming to your second question - Yes, LMS supports arrays as well. Below is the example which I tried :

**Publisher code :**

```
const options = [
      { label: 'English', value: 'en' },
      { label: 'German', value: 'de' },
      { label: 'Spanish', value: 'es' },
      { label: 'French', value: 'fr' },
      { label: 'Italian', value: 'it' },
      { label: 'Japanese', value: 'ja' },
  ];
publish(this.messageContext,LMS_Demo,{selectedValues: options});
```

**Subscriber Code :**
Note : You need to call `subscribeToChannel()` from your LWC's connectedCallback.

```
subscribeToChannel(){
        if (!this.subscription) {
            this.subscription = subscribe(
                this.messageContext,
                LMS_Demo,
                (message) => this.handleMessage(message),
                { scope: APPLICATION_SCOPE }
            );
    
        }
    }
    
    handleMessage(message){
      console.log("from LMS ", message.selectedValues);
    }
```

But in case of large data sets , its preferred to stringify your data and pass using LMS.
For more info , refer - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_message_channel_intro

Comment: @blank paper , consider accepting this as the answer if this helps you.